# start over iOS app

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, app-store

I have an app published in the store, which i want to change so much its internal working, that i decided to start over. I successfully finished the new version of my app, but when i install the previous version of the app, and run the new version from xcode to check if everything is compatible, i get "Could not change executable permissions on the application".

What i did was to change the bundle identifier of the new version of the app to match the old one, but i cant get it to run under the same name. Do I need to do something else? The app runs great if the old one isn't installed, but when I have the old one installed, and I want to run the new one, so it replaces the old one, i get the error i mentioned above.

Thanks

Comment: Might be any kind of debug installation process, did you try to install it over the older version with AdHoc or Release `.ipa` file ? I'd also check the version to be higher, it worked fine for me with the minor version installing over the major though.

Comment: yes, i've tried. i still get that error. and the error works only one way. if i have the new one installed, and i install the old one it runs fine. if i try to do it the other way around i get "Could not change executable permissions on the application". when you did that, the only thing that you've changed was the bundle identifier?

Comment: I did not change the bundle ID, what I tried is to install the same app with the same bundle ID (which i understood you need to do) but with the different bundle versions, the guess was that system prevents the older version to be installed over the newer and you might use like version 2.1 for the old app and 1.0 for the new, but it worked for me fine. On your place i'd test it with another device and get the Apple tech support if the problem remains: https://developer.apple.com/support/technical/

Answer (score 2):

The problem I had was related with the use of unreleased iOS beta software. It is solved by testing my apps on a device running the last released OS (iOS 5.1.1 at the moment).

Comment: I had the same problem today, it's definitely an issue with iOS 6/XCode 4.5-DP3.

Comment: I have it with XCode 4.5 beta 4.

Comment: I just got this "Could no change executable permissions on the application" with XCode 4.5 GM !!!!! App ran fine yesterday.

Comment: Running iOS6 GM/XCode 4.5 GM, I get the error "Could not change executable permissions on the application" if I try to run my app on the phone when the App Store version is already there. If I delete the app store version it installs fine. Bottom line: WILL Users be able to upgrade with new version??

Comment: @Fraggle has the answer, delete the old app from the device/simulator. I've up-voted the comment, but it would be great if that comment was posted as proper answer--I would happily up-vote that too.

Comment: I deleted my answer as the proper one. Is up to @Fraggle to post it now !

Answer (score 2):

i think you should try to  remove the app that have same bundle identifier in you iOS device ,
hope this can help you!

Comment: This works but it is a horrible solution. I typically test upgrade paths by installing the app store version and then updating.

I guess I'll have to pull old versions from my source control instead, which is doable - but a pain!

Answer (score 0):

I just had this same issue which almost caused me a meltdown. I'm on xcode 5.1 and ios 6. My answer was to delete the app on my iPad by holding my figure over the app icon, then pressing the 'x' that appears next to it. Then I went back into xcode and built the project.