# Could not change executable permissions on the application

Tags: xcode, ios6, xcode4.5

Just updated to iOS 6 sdk and latest Xcode and get this when trying to build to my 3gs.
I 've added armv6 under valid architectures?

"Could not change executable permissions on the application"

Comment: The same happens on my iPhone 5. I tried deleting Xcode and reinstalling. I think some components are lingering around.

Comment: I just unplugged the phone and uninstalled the app. Ba-da-bingo!

Answer (score 344, accepted):

I could solve it erasing an application that I had previously uploaded using the same Bundle Identifier (xcode get's confused doing the chmod). Try checking the log from xCode Organizer (Your device's Name -> Console) you should get information from that log. Good luck!

Comment: yes this was reason I managed to work out what I was doing wrong your answer is correct. Thank you!

Comment: But will my users be able to upgrade ??? I have an app that is selling. Created new version, and if I try to run on iPhone with App Store version I get this error. So what happens if I release new version in the app store?? Help.

Comment: @Ignacio - No, I can't advise them to do that !!! Exactly what I want to avoid. I don't even know who my users are. The upgrade has not been released (approved but not released).

Comment: @Fraggle - I've changed the name of three of my apps in this way prior to iOS6 without problem. I'm now getting your issue with the current app I'm trying to rename... This is either a) a bug in XCode 4.5 (asking the device to do something it can't) or b) a policy change which states that you can't change the app name after an app is released... It should in theory be fixed if you change your app name 'back' to what it was with your previous version. That's what I'll be doing for now!

Comment: To change the app name 'back' go into the app Build Settings and find Product Name. Change it to whatever the home screen icon text is for your current version. Hopefully this will work!

Comment: @RedNightingale This has nothing to do with app name for me. I did not change app name or bundle identifier. I'm updating an existing app, so definitely not changing anything except some code.

Comment: What does the device's console output look like when you try and run the app?

Comment: I used the same BundleIdentifier for two different projects on one device. Changing the BundleID did the trick.

Comment: yeah guess it was cause of having 2 apps with the same bundle identifier :)

Comment: This works, but it would be nice if there was a way to do this without losing app data.

Comment: I think the below response http://stackoverflow.com/a/12668605/102133 is more appropriate

Comment: Friday afternoon with a deadline in about 5 minutes, this was the first thing I wanted to read. You legend.

Comment: @Fraggle - if you go to `Build Settings` -> `Packing` -> `Product Name`. Change the value with the same product name you can see on the iTunes Connect portal. Go to Binary Details and then copy the Entitlements app name. In that way you can make updates on the App Store ;)

Answer (score 116):

folks, i get this resolved 
- because i already have the same app using the same bundle identifier installed on the phone.
- what you need to do is to delete all those apps on your iphone which is using the same bundle identifier name.
- you'll make it!!

Comment: yes. I delete the app in the device .and try again, It work well.

Comment: That is perfect, Just what I needed

Comment: Thanks. But when I will upload to appstore, users must be erase the old version befor to dowload the new version? or the upgrade is possible without erase the old version one?

Comment: Perfect - this was precisely the problem in my case. Thanks.

Comment: Doesn't help much when you're trying to test migration… ;)

Answer (score 13):

You probably have a different target name. You can start the app from scratch, but you'll need the same target name and the same bundle identifier.

Comment: yes I just encountered this problem. target name and bundle identifier must be same. After setting this, the error disappears.

Comment: I found this to be the correct answer, it's not necessary to delete the app, at least in my case.

Comment: Yes. This is right. Since I need to keep some config of the existing and then overwrite with the debug ap with different target, then I got this error. (I installed an ad hoc app to debug push message).

Comment: target name and bundle identifier need not be same. I have a working example working in front of me.

Comment: Keeping the same bundle identifier and target name worked. Thanks!!

Answer (score 13):

Delete the apps that were already installed on iphone/ipad with the same Bundle identifier.iphone/ipad gets confused with the apps with same bundle identifier. so change change the Bundle identifier of the current app or delete the app that was already installed.

Answer (score 7):

It can happen when you launch the app from Xcode and you have the appstore version installed in the phone with the same bundle-id but a different name. In my case I'm using App_Beta when in the appstore is App.
If the two versions does not have the same product name you wont be able to test the upgrade from the old to the new version. To solve make the names match.

Answer (score 4):

I went into the Organizer and selected the Applications underneath my test device.  Even though I had deleted the application on my device itself, it still showed up in my list of applications.  I deleted it there, and this took care of the issue for me.

Answer (score 3):

You need to delete all the app's using the same bundle identifier. I did the same, but still the same error persisted on my iPod, i cleaned the (<kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>k</kbd>) the build and restarted the iPod and i was able to run the app on the iPod.

Answer (score 3):

You just delete the apps that were already installed on your device with the same identifier.

Answer (score 3):

I ran into the same problem, but I needed to keep the current installed App in the device for debug purposes. My solution was to use the same:

1. Target Name
2. Bundle identifier
3. Product Name

Answer (score 2):

I had this error, and what fixed it for me was Product Name under Build Settings. I had changed it to something else, and started getting this error. I changed it back and it fixed it.

Comment: Changed it back to what? More details please

Comment: Presumably changed it back to what he called it beforehand.

Answer (score 1):

Just delete all the previous versions of the application. Due to mismatch/confusion about bundle identifier it happens. 
I removed all the existing application with the similar identifier and was able to install.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this error message simply by unplugging the USB cable, and plugging it in again after a few seconds. YMMV!

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that your device is not set to two applications with the same Bundle ID.

Answer (score -1):

I had this error when I tried copying and pasting one xcode project to build another app. What I had to do was change the bundle identifier name to something different than my previous app.

[image]

Answer (score -8):

> Could not change executable permissions on the application

***Cause***: I had icons in the files system named `29x29.png`, `58x58.png`, `72x72.png`, etc. I had soft links (`ln -s`) with the required names per [App Icons on iPad and iPhone](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1686/_index.html). For example, `Icon-Small.png` was a link to the real file `29x29.png`.

I did this because my program runs on different platforms, from mobile phones to desktops. Android, Apple and Microsoft all have similar requirements. So "one set of icons" and "different links for different OS" made the most sense to me.

***Fix***: Don't use links. Apple does not tell you that. And their error message of *"Could not change executable permissions on the application"* is useless.

---

Looking at all the different answers (and causes), it looks like lots fo things can cause it.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why all the down votes? I explained how to duplicate the problem, and how to fix the problem in the example case. Note well: Apple does *not* prohibit links to sanely named files (29x29.png for example). Review the documentation for the linked article.

Comment: @William - the question was about the error *"Could not change executable permissions on the application"*. Links using required names pointing o the PNGs will cause it. The fix is to *not* use links. Apple does not tell you that.