# Could not change executable permissions on the application appears when changing the bundle identifier

Tags: iphone, ios

I just change the Bundle identifier, and when I run the application, a pop up message appears which is:
"Could not change executable permissions on the application."

In fact, I have no idea about resolving it, I appreciate your helps, thank you.

Comment: How about searching? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12547706/could-not-change-executable-permissions-on-the-application

Comment: thank you, I resolve it by deleting all the applications that using the same bundle identifier, but I didn't know the reason of this conflict!

Answer (score 5):

You can not use more than one app with same bundle identifier because it create conflicts. That is the reason that you are getting pop up message.