# Phonegap: could not change executable permissions on the application

Tags: ios, cordova

I have phonegap application in app store. Now i want update it. I created new project in xcode, updated confog.xml:
id - the same like in base app; 
version code - increased by one; 
version - also increase by one

Now, when i try run it from xcode on device where installed previos version i get error: could not change executable permissions on the application

Solution with previously remove old app not suitable, because i need data that already collected by user

Solution with Distribution provisioning profile instead off Development profile, maybe works, but i didn't found how to add distribution profile to testing

So question - how to test it?

Thanks

Comment: This error occurs when you try to install an app into the device via xcode. This means that there is already an app in the device with the same bundle id, whose executable is mismatching with the new one you are trying to install. To fix this, you have to delete the old app with the same bundle id from the device.

Comment: Here is the link which will help you

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12547706/could-not-change-executable-permissions-on-the-application

Answer (score 1):

```
This error occurs when you try to install an app into the device via xcode. This means that there is already an app in the device with the same bundle id, whose executable is mismatching with the new one you are trying to install. To fix this, you have to delete the old app with the same bundle id from the device.
```

Comment: This was the right answer for me, @iana - maybe you should mark this as correct

Comment: @ Billy Moon If its work for you then you should voted this answer.