# Installing iOS app over old version on iOS 6

Tags: ios, xcode, installation, app-store

My app has been live in the app store for a while. It saves data locally using `NSUserDefaults`. Some of the saved data needs to be automatically updated when users install the app update I'm working on.

To test, I install the old app, do a few things to save the data locally, then install the updated app over the old app, and make sure the data updates correctly. This has worked on devices running iOS 7.

I'm having trouble installing the updated app over the old app on a device or simuator running iOS 6. I've received a few different error messages, looked them up, and didn't really find any answers that worked.

**Will users running iOS 6 have trouble installing the updated app on their devices?**

I'm wondering if the issue has something to do with Xcode 5.1 debug builds. Maybe the issue goes away when users install a release build distributed by Apple.

**Edit:** I tried the advice in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12547706/could-not-change-executable-permissions-on-the-application) and nothing seemed to work.

Comment: Unless you provide more details there is no way for anyone to help. Do you have a device with iOS 6 to test on?

Comment: @rmaddy Yes, I've tested on a device running iOS 6 and the install fails. Finding the error message now.

Comment: @rmaddy The install fails with the error "Could not change executable permissions on the application". I searched for this error, saw that other people received it, but couldn't figure out if it matters when the app is distributed from the app store.

Comment: try this solution: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12696185/1336105